# Getting places using Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying to get all place_ids related to car in google api.
But unfortunately this link always return me maximum of 200.
I know that google documentation has said its maximum of 200.
Is there any way to get more than 200 in one request?

Here is the link that i used.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=14.63297,121.03328&radius=50000&types=car_dealer|car_rental|car_repair|car_wash|gas_station|parking&key=MY_API_KEY
```

Comment: As I read in manual there is no a way. But you can decrease the size of radius and increase amount of points.

Comment: Oh okay. Maybe that's the only solution. thans